# Retrieving a folder of Images from Azure Blob storage -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-storage

I'm writing a program that uploads images to Azure blob storage and stores them in folders. The images are stored in an image array before they're uploaded.

Now I want to be able to retrieve a folder of images and store it back in an image array.

Do I need to create a blobContainer locally with the folder name I'm looking to download and then download it?

Or can I only download the images one by one.

```
//Creating the Container
let blockBlob = blobContainer.blockBlobReference(fromName: "folderName")
blockBlob.properties.contentType = "image/png"

//Download the container
blockBlob.download(to: imageArray, completionHandler: {(NSError) -> Void in })
```

Is this the correct idea for how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, we can't download the whole container/folder using one single API/SDK operation according to [Azure Blob REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/operations-on-containers).

So your second assumption is right--download your images to local stream/file one by one in a loop.

You can add one more [DownloadBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage#download-a-blob) step in [ListBlobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage#list-the-blobs-in-a-container) process.

**Update**

Get your folder aka the directory using method `directoryReferenceFromName` in container.

Then use `listBlobsSegmentedWithContinuationToken` to list and download blobs in directory. And the `count` method is also available.

Comment: I thought that would be the case, is there any way of knowing the count of images in the folder or will I have to loop through until an image isn't returned and break out the loop that way

Comment: @benjiiiii You can see `results.blobs.count` in the demo of [ListBlobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage#list-the-blobs-in-a-container) I mentioned. Is this what you want?

Comment: Kind of - however that would return a count of the number of folders within my container. Can I set my container to be the folder within my main container? Then use the count method?

Comment: @benjiiiii Have updated my answer with explicit methods, you can have a try.